# Getting USB's to work in VirtualBox

Tags: permissions, usb, virtualbox, group

I know there is a fair bit of material on this issue but I have tried it all and cannot get it to work.

Here's where I'm at:
Laptop: Lenovo G50-70
Host - Mint 17.2 uptodate.
Guest - Windows 7 32bit.
Vbox 5.1.26 VBox Ext Pack 5.1.26 (as per preferences in VBox)
Vbox Guest Additions also added and working for shared net drive
Installed the VBox extension pack and enabled USB2.0 on guest.
Booted Win7 guest which installed the correct drivers for USB. Device Mngr says all ok
In host: sudo usermod -aG vboxusers joe (and also variant -a -G) seemed to go fine
Rebooted host after any group changes to take effect.
Checked ID and 125(vboxusers) there
Also checked users and groups and added me to 1001(virtualbox)
In users and groups added me to group vboxsf with ID 111
Also changed my long username to match joe (in case this was a problem - joe is the only user other than root)

I have tried different usb drives 3.0 and 2.0 and with no joy. The windows computer simply will not see any connected usb devices. Using a 2.0 port on host computer. VBox is simply not seeing any connected USB devices whether mounted or unmounted.

Some have suggested running VBox as root but I have tried that but it runs a different VBox with no machine in it (makes sense as root isn't joe I guess!)

Anyone any idea what the problem is?

Comment: [SOLVED] - Looking further around the web on this I saw comments about Ubuntu distributions of VBox and Oracle ones and the former not supporting USB's (now irrelevant as of V4 there's only one). For whatever reason, that  got me thinking about the version of VBox I had installed. I checked with the software manager in Mint and the most popular version is 5.0.2. So I installed that. I also had to downgrade the Ext Pack to match. Voila - it then worked! There's some problem with Mint 17.2 and Vbox 5.1.26. Joe

Comment: Good you had it working. I suggest you answer your own question with your solution and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking further around the web on this I saw comments about Ubuntu distributions of VBox and Oracle ones and the former not supporting USB's (now irrelevant as of V4 there's only one). For whatever reason, that got me thinking about the version of VBox I had installed. I checked with the software manager in Mint and the most popular version is 5.0.2, so I installed that. I also had to downgrade the Ext Pack to match. Voila - it then worked! There's some problem with Mint 17.2 and Vbox 5.1.26.